# Performing post through Chrome extension, where does it go?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, http-post

I want the below code to execute when I push the button I have added to my chrome browser through my extension:

```
    <script>
var formData = new FormData();  
var html = document.innerHTML;
formData.append("time", "12:00:00");  
formData.append("html",document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML);  

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();  
xhr.open("POST", "https://www.mywebsite.com/index");  
xhr.send(formData); 
</script>
```

my issues is I have no idea where does this go? background html? manifest? I cant understand how it works even after  reading the document about the architecture can anyone help me?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should go into background page. In order for it to work you need to add `https://www.mywebsite.com` to domain permissions first. It is all explained [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/xhr.html) with examples.

To catch browser action button click:

```
//background.html
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    var formData = new FormData();  
    ...
});
```

This will work only if you don't have a popup defined.

Comment: thanks seg, but this is what I dont get, how do I interact with it? I dont get how do I link the clicking action on my button with something that lives in the backgroundhtml page

Comment: @Max It depends where your button is located. Do you mean like browser action button?